# Determine what $\dim(X)$ is.

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers, vector-spaces, vectors, independence

How would I determine the dimension of the following subspace?

$$X=\left\{\ \begin {pmatrix} -ix\\ 3x \\ i^2x \end{pmatrix} \in \mathbb{C^3} \ \biggm| x \in \mathbb {C}  \right\}\subseteq\mathbb{C}^3$$

I'm unsure as to how to start my solution so any hints would be great!

Comment: $X = span(v)$ where $v=(-i,3,-1)$. Can you figure out from here?

Comment: what is your understanding of $\dim X$ ?

Comment: Notice that we have to do here with a LInear Space over $C$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
\begin {pmatrix} -ix\\ 3x \\ i^2x \end{pmatrix} = x \begin {pmatrix} -i \\ 3 \\ i^2 \end{pmatrix}
$$
There's only one "free" variable.

Comment: Lol you beat me by a few seconds. I suck at doing matrices in $\LaTeX$

Comment: @RushabhMehta : I just copied and pasted.

Comment: that would have been smart.